# Difference between def m(p: T forSome {type T} and def m1(p:Any), is there any ? Explanation needed based on Scala Language Specification

Tags: scala, types, existential-type

```
object ExistentialTypesAsFunctionParameters extends App{

      def m(p: T forSome {type T})=p.toString
      def m1(p:Any)=p.toString
      println(m("Hello"))
      println(m1("Hello"))
}
```

This program runs and prints `Hello` twice.

What is the difference between `m` and `m1`, is there any ?

What are the values that are allowed by the existential type `T forSome {type T}` as compared to `Any`?

**Most importantly**:

How can these questions be answered based on the Scala Language Specification ?

In other words, an explanation is needed in terms of the Scala Language Specification.

[image]

EDIT:

Follow up question:

```
class Top
class Middle extends Top {override def toString()="Middle"}
class Bottom extends Middle
object ExistentialTypesAsFunctionParameters extends App{    
  def m3(p: T forSome {type T >: Middle })=p.toString
  println(m3(new Middle))
  println(m3(new Bottom))
  println(m3(new Top))
}
```

This code compiles and runs.

But I would expect `println(m3(new Bottom))` not to compile because of the restriction `T forSome {type T >: Middle }` that should mean that any value `v` whose type can be a subtype of `Middle` should not have the type `T forSome {type T >: Middle }`.

So why does this code still compile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the expression `p` in `p.toString` is the skolemization of `T forSome {type T}`, per SLS section 6.1:

> The following skolemization rule is applied universally for every
>   expression: If the type of an expression would be an existential type
>   T , then the type of the expression is assumed instead to be a
>   skolemization (§3.2.10) of T .

which we can see is `Any` by following the skolemization rules in your quote.

So *when used as the type of an expression*, `T forSome {type T}` has the same effect as `Any`, and it will admit the same possible values. And when used as a type, it will be considered to conform to a given type iff its skolemization does (per 3.5.2). But the types are *not* equivalent as defined in section 3.5.1. That said, I can't see any way to distinguish between them even at the type level.

Edit: `T forSome {type T >: Middle}` is just any supertype of `Middle`, i.e. again `Any` conforms to this. `Any >: Middle` so `Any <: T forSome {type T >: Middle}`, and `Bottom <: Any`, so `Bottom` can still be passed. If you want to prevent subtypes of a particular type being passed you can use a typeclass that doesn't exists for those subtypes (by deliberately creating an implicit resolution conflict for those subtypes).

Comment: Could you please also comment on the follow up question in the edit ?

Comment: Thank you for commenting on the follow up question, this is very helpful explanation.